# TypeScript type-dependent input parsing

Tags: typescript, types

I am wondering how I would be able to use Type information to conditionally parse input. Given the below code how could I use the Interface or Type to determine the processing needed at runtime.

```js
interface Product {
  name: string;
  rating: number;
}

const raw = `
name=Coffee Cup
rating=4.2
`;

const parsed = raw
  .trim()
  .split(/\n/)
  .reduce((acc, line) => {
    const [key, value] = line.split('=') as [keyof Product, string];

    acc[key] = value;
    // Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'undefined'.
    
    // I'd like to conditionally "process" `value`
    // acc[key] = Product[key] === string ? value : parseInt(value, 10)

    return acc;
  }, {} as Partial<Product>);

console.log(parsed);
```

But as I understand TypeScript, the Type layer is compile-time and the runtime code doesn't have access to the types.

Comment: You could make a dummy variable and get the type from there. Then you can use that as a "schema": https://tsplay.dev/wQReZN

Comment: @vr. that might be the way that I have to go. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **switch** or something else for guarantee that value type matches the key:

```
const [key, value] = line.split('=') as [keyof Product, string];

switch (key) {
        case 'name':
            acc[key] = value;
            break;
        case 'rating':
            acc[key] = parseInt(value, 10);
            break;
    }
```

Comment: This is a good suggestion. What if - however - you didn't want to hard code to property names? For simple objects this wouldn't be an issue but for larger and more complex objects it would be nice if knowing the property names and nesting structure wasn't required.

Comment: @kalisjoshua I tried all the options known to me and did't find a universal one ... :(

Comment: Anyway you should check the type for both: key and value

Answer (score 0):

As you noticed, TS does not exist at runtime.
If your project is likely to parse more complicated objects, I would consider Zod library to check your types at runtime:

```ts
import { z } from "zod";

const Product = z.object({
  name: z.string(),
  rating: z.coerce.number()
});

// extract the inferred type
type Product = z.infer<typeof Product>;

const raw = `
name=Coffee Cup
rating=4.2
`;

const entries = raw
  .trim()
  .split(/\n/)
  .map(line => line.split('='));
  
const parsedObject = Object.fromEntries(entries);
const p: Product =  Product.parse(parsedObject);
```

Comment: I was hoping there was some part of TypeScript I was missing that would natively help with this sort of thing. Thanks you though for the reference to `zod`; I've not yet worked with it.